# Minecraft server CraftBukkit (Unable to access jarfile craftbukkit.jar)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I followed the steps from Bukkit.org but it still resulted in the problem I'm having. I made a .bat file:

```
@echo off  
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true  
pause
```

After I run the bat file it results into this:

[image: CMD output]
Couple of things I've already looked at:

- My craftbukkit.jar is named craftbukkit.jar and not craftbukkit.jar.jar (file extensions are ON)
- The above .bat file I'm running is in the same folder as where the .jar file is placed
- I have installed the latest version of Java
- I run the .bat file as Administrator
- The .jar file had some protection (because it was downloaded from the internet), but I removed that

Also, when I run the .jar directly with Java (double click and run it with Java) it works, generates worlds and other files. Sadly, I don't get a console or any other interface.

I'm trying to run this on Windows 10 Pro.

**UPDATE**

Moved the .bat somewhere else in response to Adam's response and found that the error was given anywhere. Specified the code:

```
@echo off  
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar "H:\Program Files\Minecraft\Bukkit server 1.8.8\craftbukkit.jar" -o true  
pause
```

Ran it again and it's loading libaries! I can tell it generated files but I can't find out where. It's not located in the same folder as the .jar and .bat files.

[image: CMD output]

Anyone know where they could be?

Comment: If it's under program files folder then it may be inheriting permissions from parent folder. I would re download if you can't find it, and put it somewhere that isn't controlled by OS. Also, I recommend using YAMS to run a server on windows. That allows it to keep running whether you are logged in or not or if others use your computer. It also manages your server nicely. Setup is a pain until you know how it works, but is super worth it if you plan to keep a server up and running all the time.

Comment: @ydobonebi Thanks for this! I'm not planning on keeping it going all the time though, just as a place where me and my friends can play together. But it's something to keep in mind. I put the files on my desktop and ran it, but it didn't work. Showed 'loading libraries' but no files were generated in the folder.